# Enviar una clave por correo y validarla en formulario PHP

Tags: php

Tengo un formulario en php que pide un correo electrónico para reestablecer la contraseña. Si este correo existe en base de datos, se envía un correo electrónico con una clave, y se abre otro formulario para meter la clave y la nueva contraseña:

```
            <?php

              if (isset($_POST['usuario'])) {
                $usuario = consultarUsuario($_POST['usuario']);
                $correoUsu=$usuario[1];
                $hash=uniqid();
                
                sendemail($correoUsu,$hash);

                echo "<form action=".htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])." method='post' 
                class='loginform'>
                <input type='text' name='clave' placeholder='Clave' required>
                <input type='text' name='contrasenia' placeholder='Nueva contraseña' required>
                <input type='submit' name='cambiar' value='Cambiar'><br><br>

                </form>";

                if (!$usuario) {
                    echo "<h2 style='color:red;'>Usuario incorrecto</h2>";
                }
               }
            ?>
```

Bueno esto funciona correctamente, el problema viene con la clave. Al insertarla para validar y hacer "submit", la página se recarga, la clave se regenera, y por lo tanto ya no coincide con la que se envió al usuario.

Había pensado en crear una cookie temporal con la primera clave y password_hash( ), para poder compararla con la insertada , o bien con sessionStorage( ). No se si es lo correcto o mas seguro y que alternativa puedo tener para hacer este tipo de validación.

Comment: El proceso lo quieres hacer en el instante o el usuario puede solicitar el cambio de pass y hacer el proceso cuando él quiera?? Si es lo ultimo, puedes usar una tabla pana manejar los hash enviados al correo y que el usuario cambie el pass cuando el quiera. Es mas si en futuro quieres escalar el sistema, ya tendrías una base para hacer lo que hace Facebook por ejemplo, que no te deja poner una clave que ya has usado antes...

Comment: @OCHOA pues en principio lo quiero hacer al instante. He pensado crear una variable de sesión con la clave, y una vez se cambie correctamente, redirigir a un documento con session_destroy( ). Me gustaría saber mas sobre esas tablas que comentas. ¿Te refieres a una tabla en base de datos? Puedes darme mas información sobre el tema? Gracias !

Comment: Claro, deja que prepare una respuesta formal (con pseudocódigo) para darte un ejemplo de como podrías hacerlo usando una tabla en tu Base de Datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En su momento, cuando me tocó hacer este proceso hice algo como lo que voy a explicarte, hoy por hoy hay muchos paquetes que pueden ayudarte y los Frameworks utilizan algo similar.

Primero voy a darte algunos datos para que que entiendas el ejemplo

- Voy a usar Passwords sin encriptar. Pero en el **oldPass** iría el hash de la clave del usuario a cambiar. Ese que hash que seguramente evalúas con un método de encriptación de una sola vía.
- Esta tabla puede ser usada en la misma tabla de usuarios ya existente, así como hace Laravel, que en la misma tabla maneja validaciones, remember tokens, verificaciones y mas.

---

Imagina una tabla más o menos así. En esta tabla es donde guardaras todos los cambios de Password de los usuarios.

| id | email | token | oldPass | token_verified |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | jose@gmail.com | Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC | josejose | 2023-03-11 09:14:55 |
| 2 | maria@gmail.com | xRF7W8RDgf5d5m | maria123 | 2022-10-11 17:34:15 |
| 1 | jose@gmail.com | K8r6KoE33io9Tbw | jose2023 |  |

El formulario **que ya tienes** insertará en esta tabla el email del usuario que quiere cambiar el Password, el `$hash=uniqid()` que ya estas creando, harás un `SELECT password FROM users WHERE email = $email` (el email ingresado en el formulario) y lo pondrás en el **olPass** y por ultimo el **token_verified** es el que guardará cuando fue el ultimo cambio de Password de X usuario. Para el ejemplo el usuario José.

Luego envías un link al correo del usuario con el token generado: `https://miweb.com/change-password.php?token=K8r6KoE33io9Tbw`

En el formulario del archivo **change-password.php** recuperas el token de la url, y yo obligaría al usuario a volver a poner el email. Aunque también lo puedes enviar como parámetro en la url generada y solo pedirle la nueva clave (2 veces por seguridad).

Una vez el usuario ingrese en este formulario su email, haces un **SELECT** a la tabla anterior donde el email sea igual al ingresado, el token sea igual al recuperado de la url y donde en **token_verified** no tenga ninguna fecha, esto como una validación extra.

```
SELECT email, token, oldPass 
FROM recovery_password 
WHERE email = $email AND token = $token AND token_verified = '';
```

Con ese **SELECT** puedes comprobar que en efecto, el token que el usuario trae en su url existe en tu tabla `recovery_password`, puedes ver cual fue su ultimo Password usado y forzarlo a usar uno diferente y todo lo que tu quieras implementar.

Una vez que has validado que es tu tabla `recovery_password` todo es correcto haces un **UPDATE** a la tabla de users con el nuevo Password elegido por el usurario y un ultimo **UPDATE** a la tabla `recovery_password` para poner la fecha y hora de este ultimo cambio. Esto ultimo es por controles y también para validar que tu token único ya ha sido usado.

---

Es probable que creas que esto es mas complicado o "tardado de hacer", pero en proyectos grandes es así como lo manejan (mas complejo) pero la base es así, imagina  que grandes empresas manejaran en sesiones sus tokens de validación para cambios de passwors.

Es mas, hace unos días comentaba en un tema acá en SOes, sobre el manejo de los correos encriptados o no en las urls enviadas al usuario en este tipo de procesos (cambios de password) pero no se como buscar los temas donde he comentado :-(

Espero que esta pequeña guía sirva para tu propósito.

Comment: Mil gracias: Muy útil lo que comentas y me hago una idea. De momento lo he conseguido hacer enviando el token al usuario. Despues encripto el token y lo guardo en una variable de sesión. Finalmente comparo el token que inserta el usuario con **password_verify( )** con la variable de sesion que contiene el hash de ese token. No obstante me decantaré por este sistema de tablas, ya que como indicas , es escalable y seguramente mas seguro.  Super util.

Comment: Me alegra que lo veas así. Saludos